# read function in c only reading 3072 bytes

Tags: c, io, eof

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int fd;
        char bf[4096];
        int buf_size=4096;
        fd = open("/proc/18022/cmdline", O_RDONLY);
        int bytes = read(fd, bf, buf_size-1);
        printf("%d %s\n\n",bytes,bf);
        close(fd);
}
```

Above code is always reading only 3072 bytes while `cmdline` have more characters than 3072.
If i copy content of `cmdline` to gedit and then run the above code on this newly created file then it is reading all bytes of the file.
I googled it and found that it reads bytes up to `SSIZE_MAX` but my doubt is  why it is reading all the bytes in second case.

Comment: You should add terminating NUL char, before you handle the read bytes as string (for example print it with `%s` format without specifying size). `if (bytes >=0 && bytes < buf_size) { bf[bytes] = 0; .. } else { handle invalid case }`

Comment: And generally, *always* check return value of file IO functions, and print error (only exception is output to stdout/stderr, there error checking is more trouble that it's worth). There are always errors like not having permissions, having wrong file name either in program or on disk, disk full... things easy to fix if you just bother to detect and report any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not rely on reading a whole file from the first try, even if you know you've allocated enough space for the read. Instead you should read in chunks and process the bytes chunk-by-chunk:

```
char buff[4096];
while((cnt = read(fd, bf, buf_size-1)) > 0) {
    // process the bytes just read, or append them to
    // a larger buffer
}
```

Quoting from the man page for [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

For `/proc` files, we can see [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) that:

> The most distinctive thing about files in this directory is the fact that all of them have a file size of 0, with the exception of kcore, mtrr and self.

and

> You might wonder how you can see details of a process that has a file size of 0. It makes more sense if you think of it as a window into the kernel. The file doesn't actually contain any data; it just acts as a pointer to where the actual process information resides.

which means that the contents of those pseudo-files are sent by the kernel, in batches as large as the kernel wants. This looks very similar to a pipe, where a produces writes data and a consumer reads it, each of them operating at different speeds.

Comment: That is another way to solve it, but my question is why this is happening only in case if file path is  /proc/[pid]/cmdline.